# Windows CMD Ping/Tracert via Proxy

Tags: windows

How can I perform a `ping` or a `tracert` on windows command line while I'm on proxy?

Edit: I'm on a http proxy tunneler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a SOCKS proxy, then no, you can't do that.  SOCKS only supports TCP and UDP, not ICMP packets, which are used by ping and tracert.

If you are using a VPN connection as a proxy, then all network traffic will flow through the VPN and anything, including PING, will go through the VPN.